# How can I create a marquee in asp.net c# codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, marquee

I would like to create a marquee control in C# codebehind. How can I do that? I tried:

```
marqueetd.Controls.Add (new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.
```

where `marqueetd` is the id of the `td` in which I want to add my marquee control.

However, there is no marquee control after `HtmlControls.`! Do you have any idea how I can do this, or is there any way to tag code the marquee in my aspx page and only add the text from codebehind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a [generic control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) with the appropriate tag name:

```
var control = new HtmlGenericControl( "marquee" );
marqueetd.Controls.Add ( control );

// set some properties/attributes
control.Attributes["foo"] = "bar";
control.InnerHtml = "<span>Some HTML</span>";
```

Obligatory disclaimer: `marquee` is deprecated; `marquee` annoys people.

Comment: thx alot for your answear , would you please tell me how can I add attributes ? especially the Text wich I want to show inside the marquee tag ? thx in advance

Comment: Sure, added more detail to my answer.